# How to create multiple application instances in CANoe COM Server Interface

Tags: visual-c++, vbscript, com, typelib, com-server

I’m trying write client application to CANoe (application by Vector). I can fully control one application trough COM server objects but if i create a new application instance, gCanAppB, the original instance gCanAppA is closed. How can i tell to the COM Server, that open the new instance in new application window?

My source code:

```
Set gCanAppA = CreateObject( "CANoe.Application")
Set gCanAppB = CreateObject( "CANoe.Application")

gCanAppA.Open ("Easy.cfg")
gCanAppA.CAPL.Compile
gCanAppA.Measurement.Start

gCanAppB.Open ("Easy.cfg")
gCanAppB.CAPL.Compile
gCanAppB.Measurement.Start
```

Comment: you should probably tag CANoe and/or read its documentation; it's possible that they have designed `CANoe.Application` to be a singleton and you are not supposed to create two at once.

Comment: Is this still valid? When I tried the above code, it opened both the config in the same application even though I have unchecked the single instance option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deactivate this behaviour in the options below Configurations/Options:
[image: Configuration image]

Comment: Is this still valid? When I tried the above code, it opened both the config in the same application even though I have unchecked the single instance option.